# Peculiar nature of $x\sec x$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, math-software, desmos

> Just out of curiosity I typed $x\sec x$ into [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and got a strange graph, (umm if you'll call that a graph).

Till now I've seen graphs that are some curves. But this function's graph is something uncanny or rather intimidating.

What it the nature of the graph of this function$?$ Is it oscillating like $\sin$ or bounded like a circle$?$

I've no idea. And if you think why I've no idea, see yourself. [image]

What is this function denoting $?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the range for x there?

Comment: Same [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/paueimlyhd) without a problem. You probably zoomed out too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Point 1 :** Plot $x \sec x$ between various limits $\pm X$ where $X=1,10,100,\cdots$ to see that there is nothing strange / weird / unusual here.

**Point 2 :** When using a thick Pencil (line thickness) we will get "areas" rather than "lines" , due to very close lines.

**Point 3 :** Compare with $x \sin x$ & similar functions to get similar "weirdness" , that is , weird curves with "areas" rather than "lines" , which will highlight that there is no weirdness. I have included that Image at the last.

**Point 4 :** When we are looking at large $x$ values with limited $y$ values , between $\pm Y$ where that limit is not sufficient to see the necessary stuff , it may be confusing & look like a Block rectangle.

$x \sec x$ : Between -1 & +1 :

[image: -1 : x sec x : +1]

$x \sec x$ : Between -10 & +10 :

[image: -10 : x sec x : + 10]

$x \sec x$ : Between -100 & +100 :

[image: -100 : x sec x : + 100]

$x \sec x$ : Between -10000 & +10000 :

[image: -10000 : x sec x : + 10000]

$x \sec x$ : Between -100000000 & +100000000 :

[image: -100000000 : x sec x : + 100000000]

$x \sec x$ : Between -10000000000000000 & +10000000000000000 :

[image: -10000000000000000 : x sec x : + 10000000000000000]

Zoom out more , to get weirder looking curve , which will make sense when Zooming in.

$x \sin x$ , looking weird , though there is no weirdness :

[image: x sin x]